# apache poi: class file for org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.Paragraph not found

Tags: java, apache-poi

Пробую повторить за [туториалом](http://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-word-with-apache-poi).

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

XWPFParagraph number = document.createParagraph();
number.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
XWPFRun numberRun = number.createRun();
numberRun.setFontSize(14);
numberRun.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
numberRun.setItalic(true);
numberRun.setText(tfNumber.getText());

XWPFParagraph fio = document.createParagraph();
fio.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
XWPFRun fioRun = fio.createRun();
fioRun.setFontSize(14);
fioRun.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
fioRun.setItalic(true);
fioRun.setText(tfFIO.getText());

XWPFParagraph address = document.createParagraph();
address.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
XWPFRun adressRun = address.createRun();
adressRun.setFontSize(14);
adressRun.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
adressRun.setItalic(true);
adressRun.setText(VillageManager.getVillages().get(index).toString() + " " + tfAddress.getText());

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("document.docx");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();
    document.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Добавил библиотеки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

IDEA выдает следующие ошибки:

1. Error:(44, 15) java: cannot access org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.Paragraph
   class file for org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.Paragraph not found
2. Error:(46, 18) java: cannot access org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.CharacterRun
   class file for org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.CharacterRun not found

---

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Projects/RequestGenerator/out/production/RequestManager/fxml/stage.fxml:13

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at main.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.Controller
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application main.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на контроллер в файле .fxml: `<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.Controller">`

Controller.java

```
package controllers;

import classes.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Controller {

    @FXML public TextField tfNumber;
    @FXML public TextField tfFIO;
    @FXML public DatePicker dpRegistrationDate;
    @FXML public ChoiceBox cbVillage;
    @FXML public TextField tfAddress;
    @FXML public TextArea textArea;

    Integer lastNumber;

    public Controller() {
        VillageRadaManager.fillVillageRadas();
        VillageManager.fillVillages();
        lastNumber = RequestManager.getLastRequest().getNumber() + 1;
        //Database.close();
    }

    public void registrate(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        int index = cbVillage.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        int rada_id = VillageManager.getVillages().get(index).getVillageRada().getID();

        try(XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument()) {
            XWPFParagraph title = document.createParagraph();
            title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

            XWPFRun titleRun = title.createRun();
            titleRun.setText("Hello, World!");
            titleRun.setBold(true);
            titleRun.setFontSize(18);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("my_word.docx");
            document.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        clearFiels();
    }

    public void cancel(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        clearFiels();
    }

    private void clearFiels() {
        tfNumber.clear();
        tfFIO.clear();
        tfAddress.clear();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        dpRegistrationDate.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        cbVillage.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(VillageManager.getVillages()));
        cbVillage.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Виберіть село"));
        tfNumber.setText(lastNumber.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: практика использования POI подсказывает, что вам , помимо подключенных библиотек, нужен еще poi-3.17, а также xmlbeans-2.3.0, без них эта штука не рабоатет

Comment: [Багтрекер POI](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57957) рекомендует добавить в зависимости библиотеку `poi-scratchpad`.

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, я тогда вообще ничего не понимаю. До этого создал тестовый проект, где просто в функции main написал еще чуть проще код. Из подключенных библиотек была только `poi-ooxml-3.17`. Программа не только удачно скомпилировалась и собралась, но и еще корректно работала (в результате был создан файл с расширением `.docx`).

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, будьте добры еще помогите)) В попытке что-то исправить полез в настройки компиляции IDEA. Результат - новая ошибка `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.Controller` (хотя раньше проблем никаких небыло). Возле значка контроллера появился еще какой-то крестик. Как это исправить? Я добавил в вопрос некоторую информацию.

Comment: А чего вы удивляетесь? Чем сложнее пример, тем больше классов ему необходимо для успешной компиляции и выполнения. Вы же не видите, чем пользуется POI внутри... А по скрину значка контроллера вам вряд ли кто-то подскажет, в чем проблема. Давайте для начала сорцы контроллера с уазанием, какая именно строка не компилируется либо падает по исключению.

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, трасировку стека я уже добавил. Еще добавил исходник для `Controller.java`.

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, спасибо Вам большое)) После добавления `poi-3.17`, `xmlbeans-2.3.0` все заработало.  А решение проблемы с контроллером я нашол сам. Вообщем я нечайно нажал `Exclude from compilation` и, следовательно, убрал файл `Controller.java` из компиляции. Просто я только сейчас понял на какую "плохую" кнопку я нажал:)